# Account Unlinking on Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm developing an action on Google that requires the user to login with my services. I was able to [implement **account linking**](https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/identity/account-linking).

That works fine; I'm able to complete the entire flow to authenticate the user using the Google Home app, but I couldn't find a way to unlink the account. The service does not appear at

[Apps with access to your account](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions)

Is there any way to unlink an account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "preview" feature on both API.AI and Actions SDK will clear any existing OAuth tokens for your action on your account.

After running "preview" and invoking your action -- "OK Google, talk to $invocationName" -- you'll be prompted to link accounts again.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if once the project is published the Service/App will appear into your account so you can unlink it?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to see the deployed service in the Home app under Services and you can unlink it from there. You can read a bit more about it in the [Google Home help center](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7126338?hl=en&ref_topic=7128170)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently things have changed since this was answered. Now there is a 'user' icon in the Simulator which you can use to unlink.[image: Account Unlink]

Answer (score 1):

You can unlink your Google account from: https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/security?hl=en

[image: unlink account]

Answer (score 0):

Go Action on Google console -> Simulator,
then click 'Testing on Device' botton,
Finally restart the test.

[image: Testing on Device Button]

Comment: fine for dev, not for production

Comment: for my dev purpose, this proved to be the easiest approach.