# Dialogflow Account Unlinking

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I've set up account linking with custom OAuth endpoints for Google Assistant (using Dialogflow) but can't find a way to sign a user out. There are no built-in actions to trigger sign out like there are for sign in (actions_intent_SIGN_IN) nor is there a way to empty out the "user" object containing their access token passed in each request to my webhook.

Has anyone found out how to manually unlink a user's account?

Similar question to [Account Unlinking on Actions on Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079546/account-unlinking-on-actions-on-google?rq=1) but no feasible answer was provided.

Answer (score 1):

At any time, you can return an HTTP 401 "Unauthorized" code and Google will consider the token invalid in the future. This is the equivalent of logging the user out".

(See [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-implicit-flow#revoke_tokens), but this is true for the Auth Code flow as well.)

Comment: This works, thanks. But it forces the app to close and Google to respond with "<TEST_APP> isn't responding right now. Try again soon.". Is there a way to gracefully handle the 401?

Comment: @Arnaud - Do you have a reference for this? (I'm not disputing it, but this is the first I've heard of a problem.)

Comment: I've the issue on a project in production. After some emails with google teams a dev in charge of this project tell me that he is fixing the _bug_ of account **un**linking. I think in few months we will have an event to send to dialogflow or an API to call to make a correct account unlinking.